# on_click(x, y, button, pressed) is not working, local variable 'pressed' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pynput

I wanted to create a script that play sound after clicking Z and next mouse button, but i have 2 issues

1.script don't detect the mouse clicks.

2. i have this error: File "c:/Users/name/OneDrive/Pulpit/python/apexretards.py", line 14, in on_press if pressed == "yes":
   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pressed' referenced before assignment

Script:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from playsound import playsound
pressed = "no"


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print("click")
    if pressed == "yes":
        playsound("skibidiba.mp3")
    pass

def on_press(key):
    if str(key) == "'z'" or str(key) == "'Z'":
        if pressed == "yes":
            pressed = "no"
            return
        else:
            pressed = "yes"
            return

def on_release(key):
    print("no u")

with Listener(on_click=on_click, on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: `on_press` doesn't have a reference to pressed. You need to either pass it, or make it global

Comment: The parameter pressed in on_click is a boolean (True or False). And you have extra quotes around z and Z. Be careful not to use same names for different purposes (pressed)

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. Your second issue is that `global pressed` needs to be declared in any function that uses the global variable `pressed`. Your first issue, clicks not being detected, isn't clear. Is `print("click")` running? I see you check for `if pressed == "yes":`, are you sure `pressed` is going to be a boolean in that case? Since you're using it as an argument to that function, it's not going to share the value of the global `pressed` variable that you declared, meaning it's just going to have the value that `Listener` gave it. You should double check that value.

Comment: i fixed the issue 2, but yes it is not printing "click". it prints click when i remove on_press and on_release